# Show that $B(R^d)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra satisfy the condition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that collection of all Borel set in $R^d$ (i.e. $B(R^d)$) is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which make all continuous functions on $R^d$ measurable

Answer (score 2):

1. First, show that this $\sigma$-algebra does make all the continuous functions on $\Bbb R^d$ measurable.
2. Assume that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra verifying this condition. Show that the characteristic function of a closed set is measurable approximating this function pointwise by continuous ones.

---

In the context of topological spaces, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making all the continuous functions measurable is called the Baire $\sigma$-algebra. In the context of metric spaces a similar argument show that it coincides with Borel's one.